# Question regarding the memory size of the function?

Tags: python

I'm a newcomer to python and I have been exploring the properties of python functions. Suppose I create an simple function `foo`

```py
def foo():
    pass
```

Now if I check how much memory is allocated for `foo`, by doing

```py
import sys
sys.getsizeof(foo) # I get 144 bytes.
```

Moreover, `foo.__dict__` is initially `{}` and 248 bytes are allocated for `foo.__dict__`

However, if I add a arbitrary attribute to `foo`, say `foo.foo_attribute="some attribute"`then `foo.__dict__` gets updated as follows: `{foo_attribute:"some attribute"}`.

Now if I again check the memory allocation of `sys.getsizeof(foo)` I still get 144 bytes, even though the function's **dict** attribute was updated. Moreover, `foo.__dict__` still remains 248 bytes.

I was expecting the size of the function `foo` to increase after adding an arbitrary attribute to `foo` and also the size of `foo.__dict__`, however neither of that occured and the memory size stayed the same.

Any reason why this behavior occurs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as `a newcomer to python` do you have to worry about that?

Comment: You got the size of the container, not of the content.